# Can I use Python requests library to send inconsistent requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I try to write a python script containing a somewhat unusual HTTP request as part of learning about web attacks and solving the lab at
https://portswigger.net/web-security/request-smuggling/lab-basic-cl-te.

There, I need to issue a request containing both a `Content-Length` and a `Transfer-Encoding` header that are in disagreement.

My basic and still unmanipulated request looks like this and works as expected:

```
    with requests.Session() as client:
        client.verify = False
        client.proxies = proxies
[...]
        data = '0\r\n\r\nX'
        req = requests.Request('POST', host, data=data)
        prep = client.prepare_request(req)
        client.send(prep)
```

```
[...]
Content-Length: 6\r\n
\r\n
0\r\n
\r\n
X
```

However, as soon as I add the `Transfer-Encoding` header, the request itself gets modified.

```
        data = '0\r\n\r\nX'
        req = requests.Request('POST', host, data=data)
        prep = client.prepare_request(req)
        prep.headers['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'chunked'
        client.send(prep)
```

The request that is actually send down the wire is

```
[...]
Content-Length: 0\r\n
\r\n
```

whereas the expected request would be

```
[...]
Content-Length: 6\r\n
Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n
\r\n
0\r\n
\r\n
X
```

The same thing happens if I flip things around, prepare a chunked request and modify the `Content-Length` header afterwards:

```
        def gen():
            yield b'0\r\n'
            yield b'\r\n'
            yield b'X'

        req = requests.Request('POST', host, data=gen())
        prep = client.prepare_request(req)
        prep.headers['Content-Length'] = '6'
        client.send(prep)
```

Basically, the `Transfer-Encoding` header gets removed completely, the data is reinterpreted according to the chunking and the `Content-Length` header gets recalculated to match.

I was under the impression that preparing a request and manipulating its content before sending should send the modified content, but either this is a wrong assumption or I do things horribly wrong.

Is sending such a request possible this way or do I have to go onto a lower level to put arbitrary data on the wire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` is a **good** HTTP client, and as such will prevent you from generating *bad* HTTP queries. As writing bad HTTP queries will result in 400 errors in a lot of cases.

To generate syntax errors in HTTP queries you need to avoid using high level http clients (like a browser, but also like an http library). Instead you need togo down to the tcp/ip socket management (and maybe ssl also) and start writing the full HTTP protocol with your own code, no library.

Comment: That is what I assumed after my unsuccessful trying. Thank you for the confirmation.